# C Struct Clarification

Tags: c, struct

I was reading through the aircrack-ng source code and noticed many different uses of struct.
For example:

> struct option {...} opt;
>
> typedef struct {...} vote;

I thought that the general format of struct was

> struct var {...};

or

> typedef struct var {...} foo;

What is the purpose of `opt` and how come `vote` doesn't have type defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typedef` creates a type alias. With:

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } vote;
```

We create an *anonym structure*, from which `vote` is an alias.

```
struct option { /* ... */ } opt;
```

It declares the type `struct option`, and a variable `opt` of type `struct option`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the way you make a variable is:

```
<type>  <variable-name>;
```

This is obvious with something like:

```
int foo;
```

Although less obvious, it is exactly the same with

```
struct option {...} opt;
```

The type is `struct option {...}`,
and the variable name is `opt`.

So this line just creates a variable named `opt`, which is a struct, with all the members described.

After that line, you've also described the structure `option`, so you can reuse that name again without re-describing the members of the structure:

```
{
    /* make structure, and variable opt */
    struct option { int alpha; int beta; } opt;

    /* Use the structure previously defined */
    struct option second_opt;
}
```

Comment: To clarify: could you then re-use the struct and just refer to it by name (`option`) rather than repeating its members?

Answer (score 0):

Type definition provides an alias for the `struct` name especially when the `struct` has a very long name and you want to rename it to something shorter.

Say you have

```
struct very_large_screen_metrics_info{};
```

you can later rename it as :

```
typedef struct very_large_screen_metrics_info screen_info;
```

what happened in the `struct` definition is that the type definition is provided with the structure definition. So, the naming  convention in the example is totally valid and is an alternative to the regular naming convention. The types is as you might expect `opt` and `vote`